# Step-by-step procedure for nested logistic regression in Incanter

Tags: clojure, incanter

After finding [this enormously helpful guide in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906272/step-by-step-procedure-on-how-to-run-nested-logistic-regression-in-r), it got me wondering how I might do something similar in Incanter. Being relatively new to Incanter, it would be lovely if someone could reproduce [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5906456/445639).

In addition to illustrating a nested model, the discussion on that answer also included some good discussion of how to iteratively generate a list of un-nested models. I'd be curious as to what is the most idiomatic way of doing that in Clojure/Incanter is.

Comment: I haven't tested this but you might check out https://github.com/jandot/machine-learning-in-action/blob/master/logistic-regression.clj